# Adding a margin-top to a paragraph with a single bold string

Tags: html, css

I have dozens of blog posts imported from a Wordpress site, where they have used single bold lines as headings (without tagging them as such). This is my content example:

```html
<p><strong>This is a heading. I want to apply some CSS to this line of text</strong></p>
<p>But I don't want it applied here<strong>or here</strong> because this a paragraph.</p>
```

All I want is to apply a margin-top to those bold sentences to clarify that they are headings of a section.

I cannot modify the HTML (ie change them for H3) as it would mean going over all posts manually. I need to stick to CSS to make the change.

I have tried this and it was a pretty good solution. But it wasn't because the small paragraph in the example was being selected as well, as it only had one <strong> in it.

```
p:has(strong:only-child) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

My thought was to find a way to EXCLUDE any <p> that had any "loose text" in it, apart of the single <strong> tag. But I don't know how to say "loose text" to use it in a :not() pseudo selector.

I want this rule to affect only this margin: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5VOM.png)

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: "*I don't know how to say "loose text" to use it in a `:not()`*" - yeah, welcome to CSS; unfortunately CSS has no means to identify text-nodes, they *are* children of HTML elements, but they're inaccessible and - so far as I'm (currently) aware - there's no way to style "element-preceded-by-text." My first thought was to check if the `<strong>` element was the only element, or if it was both `:first-child` and `:last-child`, but because CSS can't "see" text, both examples would be matched. Sorry to say, but I think JavaScript may have to be used.

Comment: Have you tried p > strong?

Comment: Yeah, it was one of my first tests but didn't work. That just matches to any strong child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution to your problem would be to query the database with a `<p><strong>` change using a regular expression.

If you still want to do it on the frontend, then you won't be able to do this with css.
I wrote one of the js solutions below. But I do not guarantee that it is perfect.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => {
  // exclude empty <p> or <p> is not has <strong>
  if (!p.hasChildNodes() || !p.querySelector('strong')) { 
    return;
  }
  const childNodes = p.childNodes;
  // check whitespace
  if (childNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE || childNodes[childNodes.length - 1].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.trim();
  }
  if (childNodes.length === 1 && p.childNodes[0].nodeName === 'STRONG' && p.childNodes[0].textContent.trim()) {
    p.style.marginBlockStart = '20px';
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p> <strong>This is a heading with whitespace</strong></p>
<p>But I don't want it applied here<strong>or here</strong> because this is a paragraph.</p>
<p><strong>This is a heading</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p><strong></strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: This sounds promising. I'd rather not do a permanent change with regex as I'm not that familiar and I'm afraid to mess it up.

I was starting to assume that JS would be the only solution. Not against it. Yours seem to work well, many thanks! Will test and monitor several to make sure it works in every scenario.

Comment: It really seems to work perfect. Many thanks! I adjusted the selector so that it selects only in the blog post content and not the rest of the website. 

document.querySelectorAll('.post-content p').forEach(p => {

Comment: I was glad to help! 

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```css
.container>strong:first-child {
 color: red;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <strong>This is a heading you want styles applied to</strong><p>but not here<strong> or here in this bold tag</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work: both `<strong>`s are first children as text nodes are not considered children

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code and added snippet. Wasn't clear about what was asked.